# Service worker not authorized for secured API endpoints

Tags: javascript, caching, authorization, service-worker

I am developing a SPA using Vue.js and Laravel as a REST API in the backend. Now I want to cache some of those API calls for offline functionality, which I am having problems with when they are secured by a token.
I am setting the token in my application once a user is logged in.
Looking at the service worker request to the server I notice that the Authorization header is no set, so I am getting 500 error codes on those API calls.

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store your data in the browsers local storage's.
IndexedDB is appropriated for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker